# Azure SQL DB: How to set External Data source to point to Read only (Replica)

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

The below is the syntax to create an external data source connection from Azure SQL DB to a Azure SQL DB

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE EDS
WITH
(
    TYPE=RDBMS,                             -- data source type
    LOCATION='serverName.database.windows.net', -- Azure SQL Database server name
    DATABASE_NAME='dbName',           -- database name
    CREDENTIAL=DbCred,                  -- credential used to connect to server / database  

);
```

Is it possible to edit this so that the External Data source points to the Read only (Replica)?
I have tried adding `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly` as an argument but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to specify ApplicationIntent while creating an External data source.

There is a feature request already created for this on our Microsoft UserVoice forum. Please upvote and follow the feedback item.
The product team actively listens to feedback and prioritizes features accordingly. You will also be able to track progress and be informed when the feature goes live.

[Be able to set ApplicationIntent in external data sources – Customer Feedback for ACE Community Tooling (azure.com)](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/35531710-be-able-to-set-applicationintent-in-external-data)